# What's the meaning of "jutul" ? Is it somehow related to "jotun" or giant?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, meaning-in-context

When I saw the series [Ragnarok](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ragnarok_(TV_series)), I saw that the word "Jutul" was used as the name for a fake family lineage which was actually "jotuns".

But intuitively, just picking the word "Jutul" as a replacement of "jotun"(for fakeness and concealment of identity), right out of thin air doesn't sound reasonable and sensible. So that sparks a plausible assumption that "jutul" is a word that has some significance and meaning of its own, which is somehow related to or tied to "jotunn" in the Old Norse language.

So, my question is, what does the word "jutul" mean standalone mean  by itself? Does it also mean "giant" in some another or weird way? Or is it a corruption of "jotunn" (as happens when any word travels from one region to another region where the people living in that other region don't know how to pronounce it correctly)? Or am I just making a mountain out of a molehill?

Comment: Since this takes place in Norway, it seems more likely that the name would have Nordic derivation, not English.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it requires speculation on the imagination of a scriptwriter writing in Norwegian. I does not appear to relate to the English language.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the derivation of the word, but it crops up occasionally in books of Scandinavian folk culture, as in these quotes that all discuss the same anecdote. Respectively, they are from *[The Fjords and Folk of Norway](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1289820538)* (1915), *[Norway and its Fjords](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1120655951)* (1909), and [*A Wayfarer in Norway*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0013JT0X0) (1936)

> In the remote past- how long ago nobody can say- a youthful "jutul," a giant and distant relation of the devil, thought that he would pay a visit to his seven sisters who lived on another island in the neighborhood.

> One day, a young 'jutul,' or devil-kin, living in the neighborhood, took a fancy to visit his Seven Sisters.

> In the folk-lore of Norway, it should be explained, the devil had many relations who were known as jutuls.

Most of the other mentions of *jutul* in the books are in quotes, although it's never capitalized.

There's also another story about a jutul and a bridge and something called a huldra, although I've excluded those since they don't specify what a jutul is.

The oldest mention I can find is from Volume 2 of the *Athenaeum: London Literary and Critical Journal* (1859), which has a minuscule entry for it. I'm only including it because it specifies the jutul's relation to the devil' it says that the jutul is *"one of the younger brothers or cousins of the devil.*"

---

**So basically, a *jutul* seems to be a giant being that's somehow related to the devil.**

---

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/jutul), by the way, says:

> folklore, Norse mythology) alternative form of jøtul (“giant”)